# Basic hardware debouncing

Tags: debounce

I was watching Jeremy Blum's Arduino tutorial series, and he explained the need for debouncing in a simple circuit involving a pushbutton. Pressing the button once should mean the led *stays* on, and pushing the button again should mean the led should *stay* off, and so on.

He implemented hardware debouncing on this circuit: using an RC circuit along with an inverting Schmitt trigger.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRJUdf5TTQQ&list=PLA567CE235D39FA84&index=10 2:45-8:45.

However, the circuit isn't performing as expected, when I implemented the denbuncing. Its behaving as if the debouncing has no effect:-
[image]

If anyone wants to see the simulation:-
https://www.tinkercad.com/things/dniOQmnxJPY

Where exactly have I gone wrong? I have checked all the connections multiple times, it seems to be what Jeremy blum had in his video...

Comment: I changed the "debugging" in the title to "debouncing", because obviously you meant that. Also "hardware debugging" has a specific meaning with microcontrollers. That would only lead to confusion

Comment: When following the link for your simulation I am required to log in. Maybe you need to make the simulation public somehow, before anyone can see it.

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know

Comment: @chrisl I have made it public now.

Comment: @chrisl i have edited the link

Comment: @PythonSchlange I gabe edited the link/

Comment: @jsotola it means the circuit is behaving similar to how it behaved prior to debouncing.

Comment: You have shortened the lower and upper pins of 74HC14, no?

Comment: @SBF how have I shorted it?

Comment: what connects the top right resistor to the LED?

Comment: @jsotola I dont..get your question.... The cathode of the led is connected to ground through a resistor...

Comment: what makes the connection between the resistor and the LED?

Comment: @jsotola the metallic rails of the breadboard....?

Comment: yes, that is correct ... now look at where you plugged in your IC

Comment: @satan29 What SBF meant is the following: The 74HC14 has 2 rows of pins you have put it on one side of the breadboard. That means, that the first on the left pin row of the chip and the first on the right row are connection. Similar for all other pins. Such chips need to be placed right in the middle of the breadboard, so that there is no electrical connection between the sides. That is your problem.

Comment: You should look up a tutorial on youtube about how to use a breadboard. Your configuration has serious issues. Fyi, on your74hc14, pin 7 is ground, and pin 14 is Vcc (power). You have power going to pins 1 and 14, and ground going to pins 7 and 8. You have the other opposing pins connected to each other as well.

Comment: oh i see @chrisl, thanks.

Comment: @lurker tinkercad offers to let you know which pin does what in the IC. I know how to use a breadboard! but i haven't worked with IC's much, and I do understand the error crisl has pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not change the lastbutton, but you compared it to HIGH. Change your code to the one below.

You can more easily avoid such mistakes, if you put spaces around operators.

```
//sp is switchpin, lp is ledpin

int sp=2; //interrupt enabled pin (interrupt 0)
bool ledon=LOW;
bool lastbutton=LOW;
int lp=9;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(sp, INPUT);
  pinMode(lp,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{

   if (digitalRead(sp)==HIGH && lastbutton==LOW){
      ledon=!ledon;
      lastbutton = HIGH; // previously here was lastbutton==HIGH;
   }
    

   else {
     lastbutton=digitalRead(sp);
      }
   Serial.println(ledon);
   digitalWrite(lp,ledon);

  
        
     }
```

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks! The debouncing works perfectly now. But for some weird reason the LED turns on at the start of the simulation....without pressing the switch or anything....any idea why?

Comment: I think because of your filter. It takes some time to charge up that capacitor, that means your Inverting Schmitt Trigger input starts low, and at the first run of the loop, your pin 2 starts high. If you put a small delay in your `setup()`, the LED starts off.

Comment: indeed. delay(100) fixes this . Thanks a lot!